# Как заставить блок который нужно скрыть нажатием кнопки не появляться при перезагрузке

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Суть вопроса вот в чем
Имеем форму 1

При нажатии на кнопку `id="firstFormSubmit"` данная форма  должна скрыться и на ее месте появляется форма 2, все это без перезагрузки, данные отправляются через аякс запрос

Необходимо сделать так что бы после отправки и скрытия формы 1 `id="firstForm"` и появлении на ее месте `id="formtwo"`, в случае если я перезагружу страницу форма 1 оставалась скрытой

Вот код аякс запроса если нужен. Работает

```js
    
$('button.classfirstSubmit').on('click', function() {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    });
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        $('button.classfirstSubmit').on('click', function(){

                            var ValueFirstname = $('input.classFirstname').val();
                            var ValueLastname = $('input.classLastname').val();
                            var ValueBirthdate = $('input.classBirthdate').val();
                            var ValueReport = $('input.classReport').val();
                            var ValueCountry = $('input.classCountry').val();
                            var ValuePhone = $('input.classPhone').val();
                            var ValueEmail = $('input.classEmail').val();

                            $.ajax({
                                method: "POST",
                                url: "some.php",
                                data: { Firstname: ValueFirstname, Lastname: ValueLastname, Birthdate: ValueBirthdate, Report: ValueReport, Country: ValueCountry, Phone: ValuePhone, Email: ValueEmail }
                            })
                                .done(function(){
                                    //alert('Data Saved:' + msg);
                                })
                                                 $('input.classFirstname').val('');
                                                 $('input.classLastname').val('');
                                                 $('input.classBirthdate').val('');
                                                 $('input.classReport').val('');
                                                 $('input.classCountry').val('');
                                                 $('input.classPhone').val('');
                                                 $('input.classEmail').val('');
                        })
                    });
```

```html
<div class="formone" id="formone">
        <p>To participate in the conference, please fill out the form</p>
            <form  id="firstForm" method="POST">
                <input type="text" class="classFirstname" name="Firstname" placeholder="Firstname" ><br/>
                <input type="text" class="classLastname" name="Lastname" placeholder="Lastname" ><br/>
                <input type="date" class="classBirthdate" name="Birthdate" placeholder="Birthdate" ><br/>
                <input type="text" class="classReport" name="Report" placeholder="Report subject"><br/>
                <input type="text" class="classCountry" name="Country" placeholder="Country" name=""><br/>
                <input type="text" class="classPhone" name="Phone" placeholder="Phone" name=""><br/>
                <input type="Email" class="classEmail" name="Email" placeholder="Email"><br/>
                <button type="submit" class="classfirstSubmit" id="firstFormSubmit">Next</button> 
            </form>
        </div>
```

Я наверное обьяснил непонятно, по этому повторюсь
Данные из форм должны сохраняться без перезагрузки страницы. При этом если на второй форме обновить страницу, юзер должен снова попасть на эту же форму.

С помощью каких средств вообще можно это реализовать? PHP, JS?

Comment: Ребят я человек совсем новый в этом всем по этому не ругайте за качество кода)

Comment: Запоминайте любым удобным способом, на какой форме остановился пользователь. Проверяйте и отображайте необходимый результат юзеру

Answer (score 1):

Вариант простой, но не идеальный:

Когда страница загружается: у обоих форм стоит `display: none`, и делаем сразу `sync()`.

Определим `function sync(){`, как:
`const step = sessionStorage.getItem("step")`
и ищем все формы, и прячем/паказываем каждую в зависимости от `step`.

Когда удачно завершится пост формы делаем `sessionStorage.setItem("step","2"); sync()`.

Comment: Если хотите делать формы с более сложной логикой, смотрите в сторону React.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте localStorage.

Еще у вас при отправке первой формы, вторая не появляется

Comment: `localStorage` не сбросится при закрытии вкладки, а `sessionStorage` сбросится, можно выбирать по ситуации